# 400 Bad Request when uploading files [Flask on Cloud9]

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, flask

I'm having trouble resolving this issue. I've got a very simple file upload form that I'm getting the following error for:

> Bad Request
>   The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

I've followed a basic tutorial and copied it exactly. I'm wondering if it's because of some permissions thing as I'm using the Cloud9 IDE and just trying to upload the files into a folder I've created in the root of the site.

application.py is as follows:

```
from cs50 import SQL
import os

from flask import Flask, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

#get the absolute directry of the server path for file uploads
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

[further in the code]

```
@app.route("/create_staff", methods=["POST"])
def create_staff():
    #define upload path
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'images/')

    #check the folder exists, if it doesn't, create it
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    print("PREPPING TO UPLOAD FILE \n")

    f = request.files['file']
    filename = f.filename
    print(filename)
    destination = "/".join([target, filename])
    f.save(destination)

return redirect("/addstaff")
```

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

i had exact same issue, and not found the solution yet, but make sure that:

1. your input html tag has `name='file'` as this will refer to `request.files['file']`
2. your `<form>` tag is marked with `enctype='multipart/form-data'`

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/